# Access to an embeded resource file doesn't work on Xamarin but on Windows App

Tags: c#, xamarin, resources

I added an excel File (template.xlsx) to the project resources as an embedded resource. In my code I want to save that file to disk.

On Windows it works well with:

```
File.WriteAllBytes("test.xlsx", Properties.Resources.template);
```

But in my Xamarin.Forms project exactly the same line does not work because "Properties" is unknown in the current context.
I searched half a day in the net but all hints I got don't work either or confuse me even more. It seems I am missing an essential piece of base knowledge here. Could somebody tell me if I can easily access an embeded File in Xamarin similar like I do on Windows?

The difference I can see in the two test projects is:

In the project explorer of the windows project I can see Properties->Resources.resx. However, the template file is not located there but in Resources->template.xlsx

In the project explorer of the Xamarin project there is no Resources.resx in the Properties folder.
My file is again located under Resources->template.xlsx

Comment: first, embedded resources are not files and you can't use file I/O on them.  2nd, on iOS/Android, anything embedded in the app bundle is read-only.

Answer (score 0):

You have to read that file in your code and then use it to write that file to file storage (application sandbox) of the platform. You can save files to that location, although you may not easily be able to access that file outside the scope of the app (say from another application).

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.